# I'am not able to delete information from my database

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I have a problem deleting the selected row from my database,In fact,I have a Form in C# that contains a dataGridView connected to a database and a button "Delete",when I clic on the button this should delete the informations from the selected row (cell[0] and cell [1]) in the dataGridView and the database.Now,I face a problem deleting the selected row from the database this is my code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (journalDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = journalDataGridView.SelectedRows[0];
                journalDataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("delete from journal where code_journal='" + journalDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'AND intitule='" + journalDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "';", connection);
                connection.Close();
            }
}
```

the dataGridView contains two columns "code_journal and initule"
thanks for an Help

Comment: **initule** or **intitule** ??

Comment: it's intitule  @Andy G :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24172625/1346943) provided by sorton9999, another issue is you aren't doing anything with your `SqlCommand` object.

After creating it, you need to execute it:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("delete from journal where code_journal='" + journalDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'AND intitule='" + journalDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "';", connection);
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

You are opening yourself up to possible Sql injection by doing string concatenation, use a parameterized query instead. Additionally, you should be wrapping your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in `using` statements to ensure they are properly disposed. Something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("delete from journal where code_journal=@codeJournal AND initule=@inituleVal", connection))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeJournal", journalDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inituleVal", journalDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
         connection.Open();
         sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are removing the row and then referencing the wrong row with the CurrentRow property.

You are also not using parameters to avoid sql injection.

You are also not executing the command:

```
DataGridViewRow row = journalDataGridView.SelectedRows[0];
connection.Open();
using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("delete from journal where code_journal=@codeJournal..", connection)) {
  sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeJournal", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
  sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connection.Close();
journalDataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Answer (score -1):

Could it be as easy as, you don't have a space between your single-quote (') and the word AND in your SQL statement?

worth a try...

Comment: thanks sorton9999 for your reply but I still have the same problem the row is deleted from the dataGridView but not from the database (I work with local database)

Comment: thanks for all of you!! my problem was solved the informations are deleted from the data base,but when I clic for the second time to show the table the informations appear again in the dataGridView (I use the binding 'MainDataSet")